# Yank first word from specific line

Tags: vim

I figured out that `:23y` will yank the entire 23rd line.
But what I want to do is yank only the first word on line 23.
I tried `:23yw`, but that does not work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Can this be done without going to the line first and then yanking and then typing `` ` `` to go back to the line I was editing on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`23ggyw` will do it. I don't think there's a quicker way.

Explanation: `23gg` moves the cursor to line 23, `yw` yanks one word.
Note that this only works if you have the `startofline` option set (which is the default). Otherwise you need to explicitly move to to the first non-whitespace character: `23gg^yw`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do that without moving the cursor.

Anyway, here is another way to do it:

```
:23norm! yw
```

Breakdown:

- `:` because we are using an Ex command,
- `23` is the line on which we want to do something, it is a range of 1,
- `norm[al]` executes a *normal* mode command on the given range,
- `yw` yanks the first word.

Add `<C-o>` to go back to where you come from.

Comment: I don't think `<C-o>` or `''` would work in this case; the previous position isn't added to the jumplist.

Comment: It is safer in general to use `:norm!` to avoid clashing with mappings unless you have a specific reason for using `:norm` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `:y` is an abbreviation of the `:yank` Ex command, that's why `:yw` does not work; it's a *normal mode* command. As the other answers have already shown, you can trigger those from the command line via `:normal yw`.

I'm afraid there's no way avoiding the jump in a practical way (but, as mentioned, `<C-O>` lets you jump back to the original position). You could use Vimscript:

```
:let @" = matchstr(getline(23), '^\w\+')
```

But that's hardly easier to type, and only suitable for a function.

Answer (score 0):

type `23Gyw` in normal mode should do the job.

```
G           Goto line [count], default last line, on the first
            non-blank character |linewise|.  If 'startofline' not
            set, keep the same column.
            G is a one of |jump-motions|.
```

Answer (score 0):

Following would work without moving the cursor as requested but it's a hassle to type.

```
:23y|norm PJ0eld$
```

or you could try working out something with

```
:23t.|norm eld$
```

Answer (score -1):

23jyw should be able to do it, it will take you to 23rd line  and yank first word

Comment: This won't take you to the 23rd line, it will move you to the 23rd line below the starting position.